# Does a power series with radius of convergence $R=+\infty$ converge uniformly to a continuous function everywhere?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I know that a power series with radius of convergence $R>0$ converges uniformly on $[-R_1,R_1]$ to a continuous function (where $0<R_1<R$). Would that imply that if $R=+\infty$, the power series would converge uniformly everwhere?

Comment: No, only that it converges uniformly on every bounded interval. Consider the power series for $\sin$, for example. Every partial sum is unbounded, but $\sin$ is bounded on $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not: The Taylor series for $e^x$ converges pointwise everywhere, but does not do so uniformly. We have

$$e^x = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!}$$

One way to see that the convergence is not uniform is to let $x \to -\infty$; then $e^x$ is bounded, while every Taylor polynomial tends to one of $\pm \infty$ as $x$ decreases.